# Rewriting an shell/awk in python?

Tags: python, awk

I've essentially got two lines of code in awk that I'm trying to rewrite in python, they are as follows:

```
1. filename=$(echo "$file" | awk -F'[/]' '{ print $2 }')
2. experiment=$(echo "$filename" | awk -F'[.]' '{ print $1 }')
```

where `file` is a *.fastq.gz file. e.g. *NoBuffer-18_S50.fastq.gz*

If I understand correctly, the first line is parsing and reading each line based on "/", and then printing the second field of each line. The second line does something similar, taking filename, separating by "." and then printing the first field of each line.

I was wondering if I could use something like regex or .split() in python to rewrite these. Or, if this is even advisable? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite the whole shell script in Python, or are you still intending to use `filename` and `experiment` as shell variables?

Comment: @jjramsey, I was hoping to rewrite the whole shell script in Python, hope that helps

Comment: `filename=${file##*/}; experiment=${filename%%.*}` is likely all you need. No need to run another program in *any* language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this (available since Python 3.4).

```
from pathlib import Path

pth = "/path/to/NoBuffer-18_S50.fastz.gz"
filename = Path(pth).name
experiment = Path(pth).stem
```

Of course, you can assign `Path(pth)` to a variable as well. This uses the [`name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) and [`stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) attributes to find the appropriate parts of the file name.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to get the file names, without extension. One possible way to do that, is using the split method as you mentioned.

```py
path= "/path/lvl/sublvl/NoBuffer-18_S50.fastq.gz"
filename = path.split('/')[-1]
experiment = filename.split('.')[0]
print(filename)
print(experiment)
```

PS.: I  used the [-1] in the slash split to get the last piece of the path, regardless of how many levels there are.